# AngularJS + Directive + mfb = Não está funcionando

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives

Sou novo com angular e estou testando diretivas.

Tenho esse scenario:

```js
angular.module(module)
        .directive(directive, function () {
            return {               
                templateUrl:template            

            };
        });
```

```html
<ul class="mfb-component--br mfb-slidein" data-mfb-toggle="click" data-mfb-state="closed"  ng-controller="tamboro.menu.quick.controller" >
    <li class="mfb-component__wrap">
        <a data-mfb-label="Fechar" class="mfb-component__button--main">
            <i class="mfb-component__main-icon--resting ion-plus"></i>
            <i class="mfb-component__main-icon--active ion-close"></i>
        </a>
        <ul class="mfb-component__list">
            <li>
                <a href="#/help" data-mfb-label="Ajuda" class="mfb-component__button--child">
                    <i class="mfb-component__child-icon ion-help"></i>
                </a>
            </li>            
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Alguém saberia dar o caminho pra isso funcionar? =/
Fora da diretiva (colocando em um .html) funciona

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer? Qual é o problema? Dê mais detalhes.

Comment: Então, isso é um menu -> https://github.com/nobitagit/ng-material-floating-button

Quando uso a diretiva ele aparece, mas não responde ao click

Comment: Você não deveria retornar `template` dentro da diretiva ao invés de `templateUrl`?

Comment: estou usando templateUrl. *template* é um html

Comment: voltei para esse problema =/
com hover tudo funciona